# Computing lots of bools with OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm using OpenCL to compute values, and then check if they're on a whitelist or not. I then need to store and eventually return the results of this check to the host.

The nature of my calculations is once the CL Kernel gets some initial data from the host, it can keep calculating successive values without host intervention - which, as I understand it, is a Good Thing™.

Obviously, the limitation on the number of calculations in this case is device memory - the amount needed to store all the results of the calculations increases exponentially with each iteration of the kernel.

I'm currently using `unsigned char`s to hold the booleans, one char for each calculation. This results in an 8x larger memory usage than plain bitfields... unfortunately, OpenCL does not support bitfields.

What's the most efficient way to store lots of bools with OpenCL?

Comment: Can you make your kernel compute 8 results at a time and return a `unsigned char` with all 8 results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no built-in bitfield type, nothing keeps you from doing bitcoded operations on any integral type. Plus, you can further increase your throughput by using vector types and calculating multiple outputs at once.

If I were you, I'd make my calculations (if possible) use vector types all the way through, one element of a vector contributing to one boolean. int4 as a general rule of thumb. Set to either 1 or 0. Then bitshift the result and bitwise or collect the result of 32 such operations into an int4 using |= which will be your output.

Thus one kernel instance can produce 4*32bit=128 boolean values and calculate all of them in a vectorized manner. Register pressure should depend on the intensity of the function producing the booleans, which if too high, might push you to falling back to using scalar types.

Comment: Wouldn't multi-byte types like int4 suffer from potential endiannes problems when transferring from the device->host?

Comment: No. If you read the part of the specs about endianness, it masks away the endianness of the device by pretending to be X, where X happens to be the same as x86 (and ARM if I'm not mistaken). So for 99% of the cases, it will not be a problem. I have done bitcoded calculations myself, so I had to do some research, but my findings were it does not matter how the device is built.